# format the dates of several columns

Tags: r

```r
dt <- data.table(date1 = c("14.01.2009", "9/2/2005",  "24/1/2010", "28.01.2014"),
                 var1 = rnorm(4,2,1), 
                 date2 = c("09.01.2009", "23/8/2005","17.01.2000", "04.01.2005"), 
                 d = c("2020-02-23", "2015-05-26", "2002-02-04"))
```

I tried with this script

```r
for (j in seq_along(dt)) if (all(grepl('\\d+(\\.|/|-)\\d+(\\.|/|-)\\d+',dt[,j]))) set(dt,j = j, value = dmy(dt[[j]]))
```

I have the following error:

> Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , j) : j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'j' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[, ..j]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is `data.table` + `lubridate` solution.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
cols = names(dt)[ dt[, sapply( .SD, function(x) {
    all( grepl( "\\d+(\\.|/|-)\\d+(\\.|/|-)\\d+", x ) )
  } ) ] ]
possible.date.formats <- c("d.m.Y", "d/m/Y", "Y-m-d") #possible data-formats
dt[, (cols) := lapply( .SD, 
                       lubridate::parse_date_time, 
                       orders =  possible.date.formats ), 
   .SDcols = cols][]

#         date1      var1      date2          d
# 1: 2009-01-14 1.9459372 2009-01-09 2020-02-23
# 2: 2005-02-09 3.7666378 2005-08-23 2015-05-26
# 3: 2010-01-24 0.6207715 2000-01-17 2002-02-04
# 4: 2014-01-28 2.8800135 2005-01-04 2020-02-23
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I don't want to have to select the date columns.
I want to avoid the stage
cols = c("date1", "date2", "d")  #columns with dates

Comment: ok.. how can you tell a computer which columns the dates are in?

Comment: Yes !  the script i published works with a data frame but not with a data table